# Question regarding answers to HW questions

Tags: discussion

I know we are not supposed to give full answers to HW questions. But what if the answer given by the book or teacher is demonstrably wrong?

This is the case for [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77444/standard-deviation-hw-question)

Comment: Good question. One possibility for the thread at issue is to close it; it has no context, the OP hasn't said anything about what they understand / have tried etc, & hasn't been back since asking.

Comment: @gung thanks. I would be more ready to close it if I thought the question itself was without merit. But I think it illustrates a sort of silliness in question asking. And my answer, showing that it is really e) would point out something about how distributions work. I am also inclined to answer since it's pretty clear that a) the question was multiple choice and b) The answer was given.

Answer (score 10):

I think exposing the silliness of a silly question has greater utility for all CV readers than forcing one OP to think a bit more. In any case the raison d'être of the rule is moot if he's been already given the "right" answer.

Comment: (+1) Without being too flippant, my general philosophy regarding any particular rule for this site is that [it's more of a guideline than a rule](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087332/quotes?item=qt0475956). In other words, while it is good (and necessary) to have some community norms, we shouldn't allow ourselves to be completely straightjacketed by them either. If it makes good sense in the context of a particular question to deviate from the "rules" for the long-term betterment of the site, we should do so.

Comment: (+1) I think this is definitely a case where judgement suggests everybody's needs are best served by pointing out the flaws in the question and providing counterexamples to the 'official' answer. The thing about not just answering homework is in order that the student derive the benefit from thinking out answers for themselves, with some guidance if they show some level of engagement. The issue here is that it's something they already have an answer for, it just happens to be wrong. I think nothing is served here by holding back from addressing the question as completely as possible.